# Identity XSLT exclude certain fields

Tags: xslt, identity

I want to use identity template to transform XML->XML, while excluding certain nodes.

Those nodes would be at different levels of the document - example XML below:

```
<root>
.    <item1>
.       <contents>
.           <fieldA/>
.           ...
.           <fieldZ/>
.       </contents>
.    </item1>
.    <item2>
.       <field1/>
.       ...
.       <field9/>
.    </item2>
</root>
```

For example, I would like only to include "fieldC" from "root/item1/contents"
and "field2" from "root/item2".

My XSLT is below. It doesnt work, I think its because I dont include parent elements of the field I want to include? But I am not sure how can I do that...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" > 
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
.    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
.    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
.        <xsl:copy>
.            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
.        </xsl:copy>
.    </xsl:template>
.    
.    <xsl:template match="fieldC|field2">
.        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
.           <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
.        </xsl:element>
.    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If anyone could help it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "item1/contents/*[not(self::fieldC)] | item2/*[not(self::field2)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (derived from the provided sketch):

```
<root>
    .    <item1>
    .       <contents>
    .           <fieldA/>
    .           <fieldB/>
    .           <fieldC/>
    .           ...
    .           <fieldZ/>
    .       </contents>
    .    </item1>
    .    <item2>
    .       <field1/>
    .       <field2/>
    .       ...
    .       <field9/>
    .    </item2>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result (the specified elements deleted), is produced:**

```
<root>
    .    <item1>
    .       <contents>
    .           
    .           
    .           <fieldC/>
    .           ...
    .           
    .       </contents>
    .    </item1>
    .    <item2>
    .       
    .       <field2/>
    .       ...
    .       
    .    </item2>
</root>
```

Comment: Sorry, the title probably caused misunderstanding. I wanted to exclude all the other nodes from the same level, BUT the "fieldC" or "field2". This solution seems to exclude these two given fields and leave the rest which is opposite of what I wanted.

Comment: @Zyga -- Then this isn't a complete definition of the problem -- you *must* edit the question and provide the exact wanted result. While you are at it, please, remove the ellipsis and give us a fully specific source XML document.

Comment: @Zyga, See my update -- I may have *guessed* what you are not saying.